# onPress not working inside of Postioned widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Im trying to put some buttons and ListView inside of Stack with Postioined parameters.

All looks fine until i try to click on right arrow icon button to go close the page.

Its height and width are 48px (which has to be more than enought to click on it) but for some reason onPressed is working like its size is 2px.

How i could fix this issue?

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MobilePortraitProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MobilePortraitProfile> createState() => _MobilePortraitProfileState();
}

class _MobilePortraitProfileState extends State<MobilePortraitProfile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 10,
            top: 40,
            right: 50,
            bottom: 670,
            child: Text(
              'Account Info',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 295,
            right: 3,
            top: 27,
            bottom: 660,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.5),
              height: 48,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [
                      Color.fromRGBO(10, 196, 186, 1),
                      Color.fromRGBO(33, 211, 155, 1)
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 10,
            height: 48,
            width: 48,
            bottom: 670,
            child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                  size: 38,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 5,
            right: 20,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 15,
            child: Container(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                },
                  child: ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    reverse: true,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              spreadRadius: 1,
                              blurRadius: 2,
                              offset:
                              Offset(3, 4), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                          cursorColor: Colors.black87,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 0, 0),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            labelText: "Name/Surname",
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            floatingLabelBehavior:
                            FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              spreadRadius: 1,
                              blurRadius: 2,
                              offset:
                              Offset(3, 4), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                          cursorColor: Colors.black87,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 0, 0),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            labelText: "Position",
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            floatingLabelBehavior:
                            FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              spreadRadius: 1,
                              blurRadius: 2,
                              offset:
                              Offset(3, 4), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                          cursorColor: Colors.black87,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 0, 0),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            labelText: "Company",
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            floatingLabelBehavior:
                            FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              spreadRadius: 1,
                              blurRadius: 2,
                              offset:
                              Offset(3, 4), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: validateEmail,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                          cursorColor: Colors.black87,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 0, 0),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            labelText: "e-mail",
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            floatingLabelBehavior:
                            FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              spreadRadius: 1,
                              blurRadius: 2,
                              offset:
                              Offset(3, 4), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                          cursorColor: Colors.black87,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 0, 0),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            labelText: "Phone Number",
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            floatingLabelBehavior:
                            FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ].reversed.toList(),
                  ),

              ),
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


String validateEmail(String formEmail) {
  String pattern = r'\w+@\w+\.\w+';
  RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);
  if (!regex.hasMatch(formEmail)) return 'Invalid e-mail adress format';
  return null;
}
```

Comment: it seems, your button only using 38 px for clicking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way, and put in at the bottom of `stack` tree,

```
  Positioned(
            right: 10,
            height: 48,
            width: 48,
            bottom: 670,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Container(
               /// container is just to check the press area
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                  size: 38,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thank you Yeasin Sheikh! It works, i've just lost 4 hours for something that "stupid". I cannot upvote you because i don't have 15 reputation but when i have i will.

Comment: thanks, and when ever you use button on stack try add then on bottom tree level,